# onclick function not working in JS

Tags: javascript

New here. I'm trying to use onclick to switch out some images that i have assigned to variables in my script but i can't get it to work. Any ideas?

```js
let doorImage1 = document.getElementById("door1");

let botDoorPath ='https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/robot.svg';

doorImage1.onclick= () =>{
  doorImage1.src = botDoorPath;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/ocejqxhu/  How have you confirmed the problem is in your JavaScript code and not in your HTML?

Comment: @Katie There is no HTML element with id=door1 in your example. That's why the code snippet doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for me until I set the src in the element to something first.  Seems to be working, so perhaps your element was not found.  Look at console to see if it was undefined.

```js
let doorImage1 = document.getElementById("door1");

let botDoorPath = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/robot.svg';

doorImage1.onclick = () => {
  console.log('click')
  doorImage1.src = botDoorPath;
}
```

```html
<html>
<img src='./missing.png' id='door1'></img>
</html>
```